# tf.keras.backend.clip not giving correct results

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

`tf.keras.backend.clip` is not clipping the tensors

When I use `tf.keras.backend.clip` inside this function

```
def grads_ds(model_ds, ds_inputs,y_true,cw):
    print(y_true)
    with tf.GradientTape() as ds_tape:
        y_pred = model_ds(ds_inputs)
        print(y_pred.numpy())
        logits_1 = -1*y_true*K.log(y_pred)*cw[:,0]
        logits_0 = -1*(1-y_true)*K.log(1-y_pred)*cw[:,1]
        loss = logits_1 + logits_0
        loss_value_ds = K.sum(loss)

    ds_grads = ds_tape.gradient(loss_value_ds,model_ds.trainable_variables,unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.NONE)
    for g in ds_grads:
        g = tf.keras.backend.clip(g,min_grad,max_grad)
    return loss_value_ds, ds_grads
```

THe value of the gradients remain the same (unclipped).

When I use `tf.keras.backend.clip` inside the custom training loop, same way

```
for g in ds_grads:
    g = tf.keras.backend.clip(g,min_grad,max_grad)
```

it doesn't work. The gradient applied to the variables are not clipped.

However, if I print `g` within the loop, then it shows the clipped value.

Can't understand where the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `g` in your example is a reference to the value in the list. When you assign to it you are merely changing the value to which it points (ie you are not modifying the current value it points to).
Consider this example, I want to set all the values in `lst` to 5. Guess what happens when you run this code sample?

```py
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for ele in lst:
    ele = 5
print(lst)
```

Nothing! You get the exact same list back. However within the loop you will see that ele is now 5, as you have already found out in your case. This was the case where the values in the list are immutable (tensors are immutable).

However, you can modify mutable objects in place:

```py
lst = [[2], [2], [2]]
for ele in lst:
    ele.append(3)
print(lst)
```

The above code will make each element `[2, 3]` as expected.

One way of solving your problem is:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
for itr in range(len(lst)):
    lst[itr] = 5
print(lst)
```

Comment: Okay! I got it! It was a bad mistake by me!